# How to disable hardware home button?

Tags: android

i have tried different approaches to disable hardware home button through  key-guard and key-down. it didn't work, i want functionality like Go-locker app. when i press on home button activity didn't close. please give me any idea about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Write this Intent filter in manifest in tag of your activity

```
         <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Add following code to your activity:

@override

public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
       this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
       super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}

Comment: sir its didn't work. please give me any other solution if u did it, can you share code with me because all the option is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Because the security reason, if any app can disable Home button, and also disables back button (onbackpress()), power button (by on/off receiver), so the app will never be killed, and your phone just shows the app. I think Go-locker has customed their laucher, you can do it, but i think it is not easy.

Regards !